# Does this function have a closed form?

Tags: sequences-and-series, factorial, closed-form, gamma-function, constants

$$k_a(x)=\sum^\infty_{n=0}{\frac{n^2}{(n+x)!}}$$
$$k_b(x)=\sum^\infty_{n=0}{\frac{(n+x)^2}{n!}}$$
I noticed these functions closely relate to $e$. By looking at them I was able to determain a closed from for $k_b$.
$$k_b(x)=e(x^2+2x+2)$$
Though I still have not found a short form for $k_a$. I do think it exists. Some integer inputs are as follows.

$k_a(0)=2e$

$k_a(1)=e-1$

$k_a(2)=2e-5$

$k_a(3)=5e-\frac{27}{2}$

Can any of you take a stab at it?

Comment: Wolframalpha can evaluate it exactly: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+n%5E2+%2F+Gamma(n%2Bx)+for+n%3D0+to+inf but it's a mess

Comment: @user404188 Interesting. It's slightly less of a mess if you replace the gamma function with it's equivalent factorial.

Comment: By mess I was really referring to the incomplete Gamma functions. At integer arguments these should just be rational / e though, so you'll end up with an expression of the form $$\sum \frac{n^2}{\Gamma(n+x)} = (x^2 + 1) e + \mathrm{rational}$$ if $x$ is integer.

Comment: The rational part can be expressed on closed form. See my comment to the Claude Leibovici's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$k_a(x)=\sum^\infty_{n=0}{\frac{n^2}{(n+x)!}}$$
In order to extend from $x$ integer to real : $(n+x)!=\Gamma(n+x+1)$
$$k_a(x)=\sum^\infty_{n=0}{\frac{n^2}{\Gamma(n+x+1)}}$$
Let : $\quad y(t)=\sum^\infty_{n=0}{\frac{t^n}{\Gamma(n+x+1)}}=e^tt^{-x}\left(1-\frac{\Gamma(x,t)}{\Gamma(x)} \right)$
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=\sum^\infty_{n=0}{\frac{nt^{n-1}}{\Gamma(n+x+1)}}=\left(e^tt^{-x}-xe^tt^{-x-1} \right)\left(1-\frac{\Gamma(x,t)}{\Gamma(x)} \right)- e^tt^{-x}\frac{1}{\Gamma(x)}\left(-e^{-t} t^{x-1} \right)$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=\sum^\infty_{n=0}{\frac{nt^{n-1}}{\Gamma(n+x+1)}}=e^t t^{-x-1}(t-x)\left(1-\frac{\Gamma(x,t)}{\Gamma(x)} \right)+\frac{t^{-1}}{\Gamma(x)}$$
$$g(t)=\sum^\infty_{n=0}{\frac{nt^{n}}{\Gamma(n+x+1)}}=e^tt^{-x}(t-x)\left(1-\frac{\Gamma(x,t)}{\Gamma(x)} \right)+\frac{1}{\Gamma(x)}$$

$$\frac{dg}{dt}=\sum^\infty_{n=0}{\frac{n^2t^{n-1}}{\Gamma(n+x+1)}}=e^t t^{-x-1}\left(x^2-2xt+t+t^2 \right)\left(1-\frac{\Gamma(x,t)}{\Gamma(x)} \right)-e^tt^{-x}(t-x)\frac{1}{\Gamma(x)}\left(-e^{-t} t^{x-1} \right)$$

For $t=1$
$$k_a(x)=\sum^\infty_{n=0}{\frac{n^2}{\Gamma(n+x+1)}}=e\,\left( x^2-2x+2\right)\left(1-\frac{\Gamma(x,1)}{\Gamma(x)} \right)+\frac{1-x}{\Gamma(x)}$$

Numerical tests are in agreement with this formula.

In addition :

CASE OF $x$ INTEGER $\qquad x=N$

$$\Gamma(N,1)=e^{-1}(N-1)!\:e_{_{N-1}}(1)=e^{-1}(N-1)!\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\frac{1}{k!}$$
$(N-1)!\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\frac{1}{k!}\quad$ is an integer. As a consequence $\quad e\,\frac{\Gamma(N,1)}{\Gamma(N)}$ is rational.

$$k_a(N)=   \quad \begin{cases}
\text{Irrational part }=(N^2-2N+2)\:e \\
\text{Rational part }= -\frac{N-1}{(N-1)!}-(N^2-2N+2)\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\frac{1}{k!} \qquad\qquad N>0\end{cases}$$
This is in full agreement with the numerical table given by Claude Leibovici.

Comment: Nicer than mine ! Cheers. By the way, did you notice the monster WA spitted out ?

Comment: In fact, the apparently complicated result from WA can be simplified. It reduces to the same formula than above. Cheers.

Comment: I just took WA result and simplified to arrive to my expression.

Comment: Congratulations !

Comment: Ahah, now that is a good proof. Well done!

Answer (score 3):

*This is too long for a comment.*

Considering $$k_a(x)=\sum^\infty_{n=0}{\frac{n^2}{(n+x)!}}$$ and using the result from Wolfram Alpha, it seems that the expression could simplify to
$$k_a(x)=\frac{(2+x-x^2)+e\,(2-2x+x^2)\left(\Gamma (x+2)-(x+1)\, \Gamma (x+1,1) \right) }{\Gamma (x+2)}$$ which, as  user404188  noticed,  for integer values of $x$, reduces to $$k_a(x)=(x^2-2x+2)\,e + \mathrm{rational}$$ as shown in the table.
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 x & k_a(x) \\
 0 & 2 e \\
 1 & -1+e \\
 2 & -5+2 e \\
 3 & -\frac{27}{2}+5 e \\
 4 & -\frac{163}{6}+10 e \\
 5 & -\frac{1109}{24}+17 e \\
 6 & -\frac{2827}{40}+26 e \\
 7 & -\frac{14483}{144}+37 e \\
 8 & -\frac{685007}{5040}+50 e \\
 9 & -\frac{2374691}{13440}+65 e \\
 10 & -\frac{80885629}{362880}+82 e
\end{array}
\right)$$

The expression can rewrite $$k_a(x)=e \left(x^2-2 x+2\right)-\frac{x^2-x-2}{\Gamma (x+2)}-e \left(x^3-x^2+2\right)\frac{ \Gamma (x+1,1)}{\Gamma (x+2)}$$

Comment: Hi Claude ! I agree with your result, of course only for $x$ integer. In this case, with the relationship $e\Gamma(n,1)=e_{n-1}(1)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k!}$ which is rational, it should be possible to simplify your formula and to find the explicit form of the rational part.

Comment: @JJacquelin. *Brrrrrrrrr* .. but I shall try !

Comment: @JJacquelin. From my table, the denominator is $(x-1)!$ and the numerator is (after changing sign)  $$\{1,5,27,163,1109,8481,72415,685007,7124073,80885629\}$$ which is not identified by EOIS. I have to go now; I shall continue tomorrow but I hope you will bet an idea before. Cheers.

Comment: No need to tire yourself. This sequence of numbers is generated by : $$x-1+(x^2-2x+2)\sum_{k=0}^{x-1}\frac{(x-1)!}{k!}\qquad x>0\quad x\text{ integer.}$$ This comes from the addition to my first answer.

Answer (score 1):

We have the [Mittag-Leffler function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler_function) defined by

$$E_{\alpha,\beta}(z)\equiv\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{z^k}{\Gamma(\alpha k+\beta)}$$

In particular,

$$E_{1,x+1}(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{z^k}{(k+x)!}$$

$$z\frac\partial{\partial z}E_{1,x+1}(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{kz^k}{(k+x)!}$$

$$z\frac\partial{\partial z}z\frac\partial{\partial z}E_{1,x+1}(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{k^2z^k}{(k+x)!}$$

And thus your sum can compactly be written as

> $$S_a(x)=\lim_{z\to1}\frac\partial{\partial z}z\frac\partial{\partial z}E_{1,x+1}(z)$$