# Calculation of $\sum^\infty_{n=0}{\frac{n^k}{(n+x)!}}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

The two series
$$\sum^\infty_{n=0}{\frac{n}{(n+x)!}} = \frac{e (x-1) (\Gamma (x+1,1)-\Gamma (x+1))+1}{\Gamma (x+1)}$$
and
$$\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{n^2}{(n+x)!}=\frac{-x+e ((x-2) x+2) (\Gamma (x+1)-\Gamma (x+1,1))+2}{\Gamma (x+1)}$$
are known; the first is easy enough to show, and a proof for the second can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2328015/does-this-function-have-a-closed-form). From these, it is easy to conjecture that, for each $k \in \mathbb N_{\ge 0}$ and $x \in \mathbb R$ there exists $a \in \mathbb N_{\ge 0}$ and $b \in \mathbb Q_{\ge 0}$ such that the following holds:
$$\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{n^k}{(n+x)!}\stackrel{?}{=}(-1)^k(ae-b) \tag{1}$$
One would imagine the constants $a$ and $b$ can be written in terms of $x$ and $k$ using the Gamma function and the Incomplete Gamma function. Notice both series above are of the following form:
$$\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{n^k}{(n+x)!}\stackrel{?}{=}\frac{P_1(x)+eP_2(x)(-1)^k(\Gamma (x+1)-\Gamma (x+1,1))+k}{\Gamma (x+1)}\tag{2}$$

There is definitely some pattern here, but since Mathematica refuses to solve even $k=3$ I am unsure what exact form to conjecture. Of note is that $P_2$ appears to be of degree $k$ with terms written only using $x$ and $k$. I am unsure how $P_1$ should appear.

---

I have tested $(1)$ for $1\le k \le 6$ and it seems to always be the case, though I am not sure how to prove this is so without the help of $(2)$. The methods shown in the post I linked above for $k=2$ seem somewhat messy; does anyone see a nice route to proving $(2)$, or perhaps bypassing $(2)$ and proving $(1)$ directly?

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+n%5E4%2Fgamma%28n%2Bx%2B1%29+from+n%3D0+to+infty

Comment: It's not an answer. You mentioned that Mathematica didn't return the case $k=3$, so I gave the comment.

Comment: @JackyChong I see. I should clarify: Wolfram Alpha does return the cases $k=3,4$ in terms of hypergeometric functions, though I'm not sure rewording in terms of hypergeometrics helps to solve the given problem. Thank you for your time.